# Does timestamp.column.name support alias in PostgreSQL Source Connector?

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-kafka, column-alias

I am joining two tables and fetching data in Kafka. If I use mode as a bulk then it works fine but if I use mode as timestamp and give timestamp.column.name accordingly then it shows [image]

My configuration goes like this:

```
    "name": "join-test-31",
    "config": {
        "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
        "connection.password": "******",
        "validate.non.null": "true",
        "catalog.pattern": "public",
        "connection.url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test",
        "mode": "timestamp",
        "query": "SELECT \"p\".\"Id\" as \"p_Id\",\"p\".\"CreatedDate\" as 
         \"p_CreatedDate\",\"p\".\"ClassId\" as 
         \"p_ClassId\",\"c\".\"Id\" as 
         \"c_Id\",\"c\".\"CreatedDate\" as 
         \"c_CreatedDate\",\"c\".\"ClassId\" as \"c_ClassId\" FROM 
         \"public\".\"Policy\" \"p\" left join \"public\".\"ClassDe\" 
         \"c\" on \"p\".\"DocumentNumber\" = \"c\".\"DocumentNo\"",
        "timestamp.column.name": "p_CreatedDate",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "topic.prefix": "test_join",
        "connection.user": "postgres",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "errors.tolerance": "all",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
        "errors.log.enable": "true",
        "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: You can't reference/use a column alias on the same level where you defined it.